# passing an array from controller to model in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to know that how to pass an array from laravel controller to laravel model .So that i can save them into db using a model . I don't want to make my controllers to heavy for that I am asking for this . When I have been saving form submissions into db where I should put my saving function ? in controller or model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel has something called [Mass Assignment](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent). It let's you pass an associative array and fills the model with those values. To make it work you have to define all the attributes you want to be able to mass assign in your model:

```
protected $fillable = ['foo', 'bar', 'and', 'much', 'more'];
```

Now you can just pass an array to the constructor of the model:

```
$input = [
   'foo' => 'value1',
   'bar' => 'value2',
   'and' => 'value3',
   'much' => 'value4',
   'more' => 'value5',
];

$model = new Model($input);
$model->save();
```

Or even shorter, use the `create()` method which fills the model and directly saves it afterwards:

```
Model::create($input);
```

Comment: yes I know about this $gurded , $fillable things . but i wanted to put the save() method into the MODEL

Comment: Well the `save()` method is in the model... If you mean you want to retrieve user input inside the model then that's bad practice. The model is just the data layer and shouldn't have to worry about from where it is getting data. What's not ok about `Model::create(Input::all())`?

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thanks lukasgeiter

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
//In Model get data from controller
public function functionname($data1, $data2){
    //query
}


//In Controller sent data to Model
$data = Modelname::functionname($data1, $data2)->get();
```